# Postgres Jsonb aggregation

Tags: postgresql, aggregation, jsonb

I am trying to achieve following (Result Required) output from POSTGRES jsonb columns, but not getting desired result using "jsonb_agg" function.
I went through this postgres document https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html, but no luck here.
Also suggest good resource for json formatting related stuff for postgres.

| City | JColA | JColB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NY | [{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":20.12,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID2","name":"ID2_NAME","type":"ID2_TYPE","amount":11.55,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":5.45,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"1"},{"key":"key2","value":"2"},{"key":"key3","value":"3"}] |
| DC | [{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":1.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID3","name":"ID3_NAME","type":"ID3_TYPE","amount":1.2,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":1,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"1"},{"key":"key1","value":"2"},{"key":"key1","value":"3"}] |
| DL | [{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":1.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID2","name":"ID2_NAME","type":"ID2_TYPE","amount":1.2,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":1,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"2"},{"key":"key2","value":"2"},{"key":"key3","value":"4"}] |
| NY | [{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":4.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID2","name":"ID2_NAME","type":"ID2_TYPE","amount":2.2,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":6,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key4","value":"2"},{"key":"key2","value":"5"},{"key":"key2","value":"4"}] |
| DC | [{"id":"ID3","name":"ID3_NAME","type":"ID3_TYPE","amount":2.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID3","name":"ID3_NAME","type":"ID3_TYPE","amount":2.2,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":2,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"2"},{"key":"key2","value":"2"},{"key":"key3","value":"4"}] |

**Required Result**

| City | AggJSonColA | AggJsonColB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NY | [{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":30.07,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID2","name":"ID2_NAME","type":"ID2_TYPE","amount":13.75,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":6,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"1"},{"key":"key2","value":"11"},{"key":"key3","value":"3"}, {"key":"key4","value":"2"}] |
| DC | [{"id":"ID1","name":"ID1_NAME","type":"ID1_TYPE","amount":1.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID3","name":"ID3_NAME","type":"ID3_TYPE","amount":5.9,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":3,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"8"},{"key":"key2","value":"2"},{"key":"key3","value":"4"}] |
| DL | [{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":1.5,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID2","name":"ID2_NAME","type":"ID2_TYPE","amount":1.2,"full_name":null},{"id":"ID4","name":"ID4_NAME","type":"ID4_TYPE","amount":1,"full_name":null}] | [{"key":"key1","value":"2"},{"key":"key2","value":"2"},{"key":"key3","value":"4"}] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consecutively use `JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET()` along with creating types for each JSONB columns and then `JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT()` to combine the key value pairs while summing up the numeric values such as

```
WITH t0 AS
(
 SELECT city, 
        (JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET(NULL::jstA,JColA)).*,
        (JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET(NULL::jstB,JColB)).*
   FROM t
), tA AS
(
 SELECT city,
        JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('id',id,'name',name,'type',type,'amount',SUM(amount),'full_name',full_name) AS jsA
   FROM t0
  GROUP BY city, id, name, type, full_name
  ORDER BY id
), tB AS
(
 SELECT city,
        JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('key',key,'value',SUM(value)) AS jsB
   FROM t0
  GROUP BY city, key
  ORDER BY key
)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT city, JSONB_PRETTY(JSONB_AGG(jsA)) AS AggJsonColA FROM tA GROUP BY city) AS tA
  JOIN (SELECT city, JSONB_PRETTY(JSONB_AGG(jsB)) AS AggJsonColB FROM tB GROUP BY city) AS tB
    ON tB.city=tA.city
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2018bf24972d12419755bceceddb03c7)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to aggregate `jColA` and `jColB` values in different subselects.

You have to unnest your `jColA` and `jColB` arrays (using `json_array_elements`) and then expand the result into fields (using `json_to_recordset` or simple `->>` operator).

After you have plain dataset, you can sum `amout` column from `jColA` grouping by other `jColA` attributes and `value` `JColB` grouping by `key`.

After you that you have to join the results of subqueries by the `city`.